# next() is not working on Express 4, Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**I learn ExpressJS but next() is not working. please help.**

I'm watching the Udemy Course about Express JS. And I coded like instructor's code, but I get such an error.

*expressJS version: 4.17.1*

index.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 1014;

app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
     res.send("<h1>Home page</h1>");
     console.log("/ Ok");
     next();
});

app.use("/about", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("<h1>About page</h1>");
    console.log("/about ok");
});


app.listen(port, () => console.log("Sunucu Aktif!: http://localhost:" + port + "/"));
```

**I get this error when I enter the /about page.**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Sunucu Aktif!: http://localhost:1014/
/ Ok
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at C:\projects\expresslesson\index.js:12:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\projects\expresslesson\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\projects\expresslesson\index.js:8:6
/ Ok
```

What do you think is the problem and solution in the code, I am waiting for your response.

Comment: Your problem is doing `res.send(...)` then calling `next()` right after.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Don't use `next()` unless you're trying to pass control to the next middleware function. In your case, you're not doing that, but instead ending the request with `res.send()`.

Comment: But I don't enter about page

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean, I can not enter the about page If I remove next()

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error is because you're calling `next()` right after you call `res.send()` in the `/` route handler. You're ending the request with `res.send()` so you shouldn't be calling `next()` right after. Only use `next` if you're trying to pass control to the next middleware function.

```js
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('I will pass control to the next middleware/handler.')
  next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("<h1>Home</h1>")
})
```

Also, use `app.use` for mounting specific middleware functions at the specified paths, just like in the example above.

What you need to do instead is to use `app.get` to handle your routes properly.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 1014;

app.use("/", (req, res, next) => {
  // will only get triggered if you access `home`
  console.log(`HelloWorld`);
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("<h1>Home</h1>");
});

app.get("/about", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("<h1>About page</h1>");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Now, you should be able to access both `http://localhost:1014/` and `http://localhost:1014/about` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

As stated by [@goto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5862900/goto1), calling `res.send()` should not be immediately followed by `next()`.

### Longer

See `res.send` as the server outputting back to the requester. After calling `next`, you are telling Express to forward the request to the next middleware, which technically is the error middleware.

In Express, when a request comes, it looks for the middleware that matches with the URL and method. If none is found, it is forwarded to the next middleware. The last of which is the error middleware and the error is thrown out to the user.